# Save simplify solve as decimal

Tags: sage

With this code:

```
x, a, b = var('x a b')
eq1 = sin(x) == a + b
solve([eq1,a==1, b==-0.1], x,a,b)
```

I get a non human readable:

```
[[a == 1, b == (-3602879701896397/36028797018963968), x == pi + 2*pi*z7004 - arctan(32425917317067571/82211366926801441775188500821661*sqrt(27403788975600480591729500273887))], [a == 1, b == (-3602879701896397/36028797018963968), x == 2*pi*z7058 + arctan(32425917317067571/82211366926801441775188500821661*sqrt(27403788975600480591729500273887))]]
```

How to make it output:

```
[[a == 1, b == -0.1, x == pi -1.11976 + 2*pi*n], [a == 1, b == b == -0.1, x == 1.11976 + 2*pi*n]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One can try the same `solve` process having exact numbers when possible:

```
x, a, b = var('x,a,b')
for sol in solve([sin(x) == a + b, a == 1, b == -1/10], [x, a, b]):
    print(sol)
```

with the output:

```
[a == 1, b == (-1/10), x == pi + 2*pi*z20314 - arctan(9/19*sqrt(19))]
[a == 1, b == (-1/10), x == 2*pi*z20376 + arctan(9/19*sqrt(19))]
```

From here it is easier to get the numerical values (for the involved constants) programatically. I understand that the question is a toy example for something wilder in practice, where instead of that "beautiful" `-0.1` there may be some `-0.8743891743127341234` - and making it exact would lead to less useful exact answers. But we have to keep in mind that `==` is an equality, that should be checked / checkable in that manner in the domain used (reals or complex numbers).

---

Alternatively, if indeed numerical solutions are wanted in a situation similar to the one described above, i would try

```
x, a, b = var('x,a,b')
solve([sin(x) == a + b, a == 1.0, b == -0.1], [x, a, b], algorithm='sympy')
```

which delivers:

```
[{a: 1.00000000000000, b: -0.100000000000000, x: 1.11976951499863},
 {a: 1.00000000000000, b: -0.100000000000000, x: 2.02182313859116}]
```

and yes, we are losing the `2 pi ZZ` freedom in `x`. But for me, sage should be used complementing the own devices, not as a machine giving answers in a best format.